# Setting css top relative to item above it when using array

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to set the top position in css of an element based on the height of that single element?

Hopefully this helps clarify what I mean, I have a list of options for a user to choose from that are div elements and are created dynamically based on an array I get from an api response.

Here is just an example of what I'm working with:

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="option">option1</div>
    <div class="option">option2</div>
    <div class="option">option3</div>
    <div class="option">option4</div>
    <div class="option">option5</div>
</div>
```

And here are a few things I've tried:

```
.option { position: absolute; height:auto; top: 10%; }
```

and:

```
.option { position: absolute; height:auto; top: 2vh; }
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
.option { 
  --a: 4em; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: calc(var(--a) + 7px); 
  top: calc(var(--a) + 10px); 
}
```

The numbers are just examples. I've tried with various numbers for height etc, but the elements always just appear directly on top of one another.

Overall I just need top to adjust by 5px or so from the position of the div element directly above it or based on the elements overall height. Is that even possible if the list is created dynamically and I can't just manually set the top for each div that appears? I don't have many options for changing the styling in other ways because I'm changing the styling of element from a 3rd party library.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Is it possible to set top in css to adjust by 5px or so from the position of the div element directly above it or based on the elements overall height?